# Rails 3 two selects with the same options but keep values unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to figure out how to deal with two select boxes with the same options (I am using formtastic gem) and force unique values. For example:

```
  <select name="departure" size="1">
    <option value="1">NY</option>
    <option value="2">FL</option>
    <option value="3">LA</option>
  </select>

  <select name="arrival" size="1">
    <option value="1">NY</option>
    <option value="2">FL</option>
    <option value="3">LA</option>
  </select>
```

The simplest way is to use jQuery, but I would like to know if there is any validation option in Rails 3 to handle such scenario. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write your own I think.

```
validate :departure_cant_equal_arrival

def departure_cant_equal_arrival
  if departure.present? and arrival.present? and (departure == arrival)
    errors.add(:arrival, "can't be the same as departure")
  end
end
```